# Java - 'synchronized' and 'final' method, declaration ordering

Tags: java, synchronized, final

I have a question about the ordering of *synchronized* and *final* for a method. Both of the following are accepted by the compiler, but is there any actual difference between them?

```
public synchronized final void update() {
    // Do stuff
}

public final synchronized void update() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: No. What makes you think that there is?

Comment: There is no difference between them.

Comment: java isn't c, we don't deal with `const pointer` vs `pointer to const` type of dilemmas

Comment: There is no difference, though one will be preferred over the other.  I believe the convention is to use the second version.

Comment: Also, you can quickly look at how JDK does this by searching strings in all places, it is really quick in Intellij. They use both, not seems strict convention about this

Comment: There is no difference between them. It is similar to public static void main(String args[]) vs public void static main (String args[]). Method modifiers do not have a precedence in terms of the order in which they appear.

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran you can write `public static void main(String args[])` or `static public void main(String args[])`, but you can *not* write `public void static main (String args[])`. Besides that, you should write `main(String[] args)` instead of using the legacy C-like array syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [JLS 8.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3) :

> If two or more (distinct) method modifiers appear in a method declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for MethodModifier.

And the production MethodModifier order is specified as (see the JLS link I provided) :

```
MethodModifiers:
    MethodModifier
    MethodModifiers MethodModifier

MethodModifier: one of
    Annotation public protected private abstract
    static final synchronized native strictfp
```

So JLS specifies that `synchronized` and `final` can appear in any order.

Therfore the answer to your question is : **There is no difference**.

Answer (score 4):

Surely, there is no difference.

But there is the de facto standard order promoted by many guide styles, frameworks, companies, and, as [checkstyle.sourceforge.io](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_modifier.html) puts it, is *recommended* by the Java Language Specification (sections [8.1.1, 8.3.1, 8.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html) and [9.4.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html))

> ```
> public
> protected
> private
> abstract
> default
> static
> final
> transient
> volatile
> synchronized
> native
> strictfp
> ```